How to display multiple randomly generated animations concurrently in SwiftUI
Consider the following code which fires Lottie animations randomly on the screen every 0.2 seconds:
@State private var animationCancelled = false
@State private var currentAnimationIndex = 0
@State private var animations = ["anim1", "anim2", "anim3", "anim4"]
@State private var animationXOffset = 0.0
@State private var animationYOffset = 0.0

ZStack {
    LottieView(name: animations[currentAnimationIndex])
                    .offset(x: animationXOffset, y: animationYOffset)
                    .id(animationXOffset + animationYOffset)
}
.task(id: animationCancelled) {
    if animationCancelled { return }
    while !Task.isCancelled {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.2))
            currentAnimationIndex = Int.random(in: 0...animations.count - 1)
            animationXOffset = CGFloat.random(in: -w/2...w/2)
            animationYOffset = CGFloat.random(in: -h/2...h/2)
        } catch is CancellationError {
            return
        }
    }
    
}

It works, but the problem is if the animation lasts longer than 0.2 seconds, it will just be replaced with a new animation before it is finished. How could I have multiple animations on the screen at once (imagine each animation lasts 1 second)? I can think of some brute force methods using five different views or something, but that gets pretty messy with the .ids.
